# Problems in mixing two JPanels in 1 JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I was mixing two `JPanels` in one frame and it gives me this output!

[image]

Here's my code in which I add the two JPanels:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Board extends JFrame{
private int width=500;
private int height=450;

Obstacles asd= new Obstacles();

Human human;    
private Dimension mindim= new Dimension(width+10,height+10);

Board(){
    human = new Human();
    this.setTitle("Athwart");
    //setLayout(null);
    human.add(asd);     //!!!we see here, I add asd (which is inherited from a JPanel)     
                        //  to another existing JPanel
    this.setMinimumSize(mindim); //
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.getContentPane().add(human); 
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //
    this.setResizable(true); //
    pack(); //
    setVisible(true);
    human.requestFocus(); //
    }
}
```

This is how my `Obstacles` class looks like.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Obstacles extends JPanel {

private int width=500;
private int height=450;  
private Dimension mindim= new Dimension(width+10,height+10);
    Obstacles()
    {
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
       // this.addKeyListener(this);
       // this.setFocusable(true);
       // this.setRequestFocusEnabled(true);
        setSize(mindim);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g); //
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 60, 30);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.draw3DRect(0, 0, 60, 30, true);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
    }
 }
```

So as you can see the height of the component is 30 and the width is 60 but the Image above shows not even a half of it!

Is there anything I can do to make that two `JPanels` mixed together? By the way,
I tried using `BoxLayout` earlier but it didn't worked. Is there something wrong or it's just my IDE is not working properly? Cheers and thanks for an awesome reply. I'm just a starting gui programmer and I really don't know how to handle things. And yeah, if you would ask the complete code, I'll edit this if it would matter. :)

Comment: Do you really think the problem could be your IDE?

Comment: Can't tell what you are trying to do by the screenshot. Are you trying to put them side by side? Top bottom?

Comment: @usar, yeah, that caught my eye, but is only a distraction, since I'm sure (or I surely hope) that the original poster was joking and knows that the chance of the bug being in the IDE vs. in his code is exceedingly low and approaching 1 in a 1000000. More importantly, the original post does not contain enough code for us to see what is happening. My guess is that you're trying to draw two images, and should then not be using two JPanels, but rather should be using one JPanel that holds two logical objects that help direct it to draw two images.

Comment: And what would your expectations actuall be, cause it looks fine to me...

Comment: More details: What are you trying to achieve? What does Human do? What does the Human class look like? Are you trying to add multiple obstacles to a single JPanel? **What overall are you trying to do?**

Comment: If you could guide me where my error was, that would be a great help. I'm sure you guys would guide me. thanks.

Comment: Guide you? Hell, I don't even know what you're error is.

Comment: I was just trying to put an image of a rectangle inside a jframe together with another Jpanel of an image of a circle. to see if how i would be that far in mixing two Jpanels together without overlapping.

Comment: Use JLayeredPane to achive this.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Thank you for a well response.

Comment: No, don't use a JLayeredPane. Yes that could work, but there is a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

Finally, you put in a requirement:

> I was just trying to put an image of a rectangle inside a jframe together with another Jpanel of an image of a circle. to see if how i would be that far in mixing two Jpanels together without overlapping.

Yes, this can be done, say by using a JLayeredPane, you could layer one JPanel over another, but you need to make sure that the upper JPanel is not opaque (`setOpaque(false)`).

But having said that, I still stand by my comment, that you look to be going about this wrong. You should not create a JPanel for drawing *one thing* and try to combine multiple JPanels because this can lead to an unholy mess. Instead you should consider creatomg one drawing JPanel, and give it logical objects, say non-GUI Obstacle objects, put them in a collection such as an ArrayList, and then in the drawing JPanel, iterate through all the Obstacles in the drawing JPanel's paintComponent method, drawing each Obstacle as it directs.

---

**Edit**
For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ObstacleDrawer extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 800;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private List<Obstacle> obstacleList = new ArrayList<>();

   public ObstacleDrawer() {

   }

   public void addObstacle(Obstacle obstacle) {
      obstacleList.add(obstacle);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      // smooth out the drawing
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

      // iterate through the obstacle list, drawing each obstacle
      for (Obstacle obstacle : obstacleList) {
         obstacle.draw(g2);
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      ObstacleDrawer mainPanel = new ObstacleDrawer();

      mainPanel.addObstacle(new CircleObstacle(new Point(200, 200), 100, Color.red));
      mainPanel.addObstacle(new CircleObstacle(new Point(400, 300), 150, Color.blue));

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("ObstacleDrawer");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

interface Obstacle {
   public Point getCenter();
   public void setCenter(Point center);
   public int getWidth();
   public void setWidth(int width);
   public Color getColor();
   public void setColor(Color color);
   public void draw(Graphics2D g2);
}

class CircleObstacle implements Obstacle {
   private Point center;
   private int width;
   private Color color;

   public CircleObstacle(Point center, int width, Color color) {
      this.center = center;
      this.width = width;
      this.color = color;
   }

   @Override
   public Point getCenter() {
      return center;
   }

   @Override
   public void setCenter(Point center) {
      this.center = center;
   }

   @Override
   public int getWidth() {
      return width;
   }

   @Override
   public void setWidth(int width) {
      this.width = width;
   }

   @Override
   public Color getColor() {
      return color;
   }

   @Override
   public void setColor(Color color) {
      this.color = color;
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
      Color oldColor = g2.getColor();
      g2.setColor(color);
      int x = center.x - width / 2;
      int y = center.y - width / 2;
      int height = width;
      g2.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
      g2.setColor(oldColor);
   }
}
```

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels thank you for another interesting lesson!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to mix JPanels, the best way to do it is to nest them inside another JPanel. For nesting, the best layouts (in my experience) are BoxLayout and GridLayout. The example below tries to replicate the drawing in your JFrame.

```
JPanel outsidePanel = new JPanel();
Obstacle obstacle1 = new Obstacle();
Human human1 = new Human();

outsidePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
outsidePanel.add(human1);
outsidePanel.add(obstacle1);
```

Furthermore, I recommend you to actually use BorderLayout in your JFrame, and then add this Panel to the CENTER location of the BorderLayout. Following your example:

```
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.add(outsidePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Usually this will give you the best results. More about nesting panels in the BoxLayout documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html). Hope this helps.